# Java Socket handling in Android different than on other platforms?

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have a very strange situation. I connect my Java software with a device, let´s call it "Black Box" (because I cannot look into it or make traces within it). I am adressing a specific port (5550) and send commands as byte sequences on a socket. As a result, I get an answer from the Black Box on the same socket.
Both my commands and the replies are prefixed in a pre-defined way (according to the API) and have an XOR checksum.

When I run the code from Windows, all is fine: Command 1 gets its Reply 1 and Command 2 gets its Reply 2.

When I run the code from Android (which is actually my target - Windows came into play to track down the error) it gets STRANGE: Command 1 gets its Reply 1 but Command 2 does not. When I play with Command 2 (change the prefix illegally, violate the checksum) the Black Box reacts as expected (with an error reply). But with the correct Command 2 being issued from Android, the Reply is totally mis-formed: Wrong prefix and missing checksum.

In the try to analyse the error I tried WireShark and this shows that on the network interface, the Black Box is sending the RIGHT Reply 2, but evaluating this reply in Java from the socket, it is wrong. How can this be when all is fine for Command/Reply 1???

Strange is, that parts of the expected data are present:

Expected: ff fe e4 04 00 11 00 f1

Received: **fd fd fd** 04 00 11 00 // byte 8 missing

I am attaching the minimalistic code to force the problem. What could falsify the bytes which I receive? Is there a "raw" access in Java to the socket which could reveal the problem?

I am totally confused so any help would be appreciated:

```
String address = "192.168.1.10";
int port = 5550;
Socket socket;
OutputStream  out;
BufferedReader in;

try {
    socket = new Socket(address, port);     
    out = socket.getOutputStream();
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

    // This is "Command 1" which is receiving the right reply
    // byte[] allesAn = new byte[] {(byte)0xff, (byte)0xfe, (byte)0x21, (byte)0x81, (byte)0xa0};
    // out.write(allesAn);

    // This is "Command 2" which will not receive a right reply 
    byte[] getLokInfo3 = new byte[] {(byte)0xff, (byte)0xfe, (byte)0xe3, (byte)0, (byte)0, (byte)3, (byte)0xe0};        
    out.write(getLokInfo3);

    out.flush();

    while (true) {
        String received = "";
        final int BufSize = 1000;
        char[] buffer = new char[BufSize];

        int charsRead = 0;
        charsRead = in.read(buffer, 0, BufSize);

        // Convert to hex presentation
        for (int i=0; i < charsRead; i++) {
            byte b = (byte)buffer[i];
            received += hexByte((b + 256) % 256) + " ";
        }

        String result = charsRead + ">" + received + "<";
        Log.e("X", "Read: " + result);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("X", e.getMessage() + "");
}
```

with

```
private static String hexByte(int value) {
   String s = Integer.toHexString(value);
   return s.length() % 2 == 0 ? s : "0" + s; 
}
```

Here is what wireshark says, showing the expected 8 bytes:

[image: highlighted: 8 bytes which are expected, but not seen after socket]

Comment: Are you sure your Black Box uses flush()? If it does not, it would explain the situation..

Comment: Unfortunatelly I don't know the answer. Can you provide more information on environment where you run your code, both windows & android versions and hardware specs? Might be useful.